# PyQt5 QNetworkAccesManager SSL error

Tags: qt, pyqt5, ssl

Tengo un problema que no doy con la solución, estoy intentando acceder a un sitio (https) mediante QNetworkAccesManager, Estoy Usando PyQt5 (compilado por mi) en Python 2.7.14 32Bit

mi código es este:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply

app = QCoreApplication([])
nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl('https://www.google.es'))
resp = nam.get(req)


def downloadProgress(bytesReceived, bytesTotal):
    print 'Descargado: %s de %s' %  (bytesReceived, bytesTotal)


def sslErrors(errors):
    for error in errors:
        print error.errorString()


resp.sslErrors.connect(sslErrors)
resp.downloadProgress.connect(downloadProgress)
app.exec_()
```

y esto es lo que me muestra en la consola:

```
The host name did not match any of the valid hosts for this certificate
The signature of the certificate is invalid
The signature of the certificate is invalid
Descargado: 0 de 0
```

Alguna sugerencia? he probado todo lo que he visto por ahí pero nada parece funcionar.

**EDITO:**

Añado esta información por si aclara algo:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QSslSocket
>>> QSslSocket.supportsSsl()
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_peek_last_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CONF_get1_default_config_file
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_KEY_get0_group
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_GROUP_get_degree
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CipherInit_ex
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve PEM_read_bio_EC_PUBKEY
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve PEM_write_bio_EC_PUBKEY
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_client_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_server_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_use_psk_identity_hint
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_KEY_dup
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_KEY_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_get_builtin_curves
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CONF_get1_default_config_file
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
True
```

Vale, ya he dado con la solución la versión con la que está compilado Qt y la que tenia instalada en el sistema no coincidían

```
QSslSocket.sslLibraryVersionString()
QSslSocket.sslLibraryBuildVersionString()
```

he tenido que actualizar los archivos libeay32.dll y ssleay32.dll de `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` pero mi pregunta es, puedo indicarle a Qt la ruta de openssl si quiero usar otra versión diferente a la que tengo instalada en el sistema?

Comment: en la compilacion debes enlazarlo con openssl

Comment: Como te dice @eyllanesc... si tu compilación casera no enlaza con openssl no vas a poder hacer uso del protocolo https

Comment: Hasta donde yo entiendo yo solo compilo PyQt5 pero las librerías de Qt5 me las descargo pre compiladas, y esas ya tienen que estar enlazadas con open ssl no?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que las librerías de Qt que estás usando enlazan con openssl... de forma **dinámica**. Esto quiere decir que has de tener las DLLs de openssl disponibles en tu equipo y localizables por Qt.

Lo más normal es que te tengas que buscar una versión de openSSL compatible con la esperada por Qt o montarla por tus propios medios (si no te dicen nada lo mejor es montar la última versión estable).

Para evitar interferencias con otras posibles versiones de la librería lo mejor es colocar tus DLLs junto al ejecutable, ya que será ahí donde primero intente encontrar las librerías.

Esta solución evitará que se te olvide llevarte las DLLs contigo cuando te lleves el ejecutable a otro equipo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya esta solucionado como he indicado arriba era un problema por usar versiones distintas,

Comment: @divadr he actualizado al respuesta para adaptarla a lo que me has contado. Si crees que con lo expuesto se soluciona el problema márcala como solución para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes con el mismo problema. Un saludo